# Can I make UI Router for React work starting from a subpath within UI Router for Angular?

Tags: angular-ui-router

My company is in the process of migrating from (Angular 1 + UI Router) to (React + UI Router).

While migrating bottom-up, is there any way to port an entire subtree from Angular's UI Router state tree to be managed by an instance of UI Router for React?

Thank you!

Comment: hm I actually have the same idea, but I'm not sure if that is possible